# Create and Call Stored Procedures in cosmos mongodb through .net Core

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure and call it through .net core application.
This is how I created the SP -

```
var sysJs = azureDatabase.GetCollection(“System.js”);
var code = File.ReadAllText("…path\sum.js");
var codeDocument = new BsonDocument(“value”, new BsonJavaScript(code));
codeDocument.Add(new BsonElement("_id", “mathSum”));
sysJs.InsertOne(codeDocument);
```

2 Failed ways of calling it -

```
BsonValue bv = azureDatabase.Eval(“addNumbers(2,3)”);
```

where azureDatabase is Database reference object

```
var command = new JsonCommand($"{{ eval: “addNumbers({1},{2})” }}");
var result = azureDatabase.RunCommand(command)[“retval”].ToInt32();
```

which gives an exception that eval is not supported

Comment: The docs I've seen suggest stored procedures only work through the SQL API to Cosmos, not Mongo. If you're building something new, you should consider using the SQL API and SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedures and User Defined Functions are part of the Core/SQL  API and relevant SDKs for various languages. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript) for the same.